# Swift - App store reject - partial apply forwarder for reabstraction thunk helper

Tags: ios, swift, thunk

My app is getting rejected by Apple. It works perfectly fine as an ADHOC built but crashes when Apple does its testing. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

The error im getting is (crash log) :

```
 12  nFocus Admin                   0x100057f0c nFocus_Admin.DescriptionViewController.(sendUpdate (nFocus_Admin.DescriptionViewController) -> () -> ()).(closure #1) (DescriptionViewController.swift:109)
13  nFocus Admin                    0x100056bd8 partial apply forwarder for reabstraction thunk helper from @callee_owned (@in (ObjectiveC.NSData!, ObjectiveC.NSURLResponse!, ObjectiveC.NSError!)) -> (@out ()) to @callee_owned (@owned ObjectiveC.NSData!, @owned ObjectiveC.NSURLResponse!, @owned ObjectiveC.NSError!) -> (@unowned ()) (DescriptionViewController.swift:0)
```

My Code is -

```
func sendUpdate(){
            //Activity Indicator
            activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView (frame: CGRectMake (0, 0, 50, 50))
            activityIndicator.center = self.view.center
            activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
            activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.Gray
            view.addSubview(activityIndicator)
            activityIndicator.startAnimating()
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginIgnoringInteractionEvents()
            //Make request to server
            var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://******(actual site value hidden)/sendUpdate.php")!)
            request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
            var todaysDate:NSDate = NSDate()
            var dateFormatter:NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMMM dd, yyyy"
            var date:String = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(todaysDate)
            println(date)
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "h:mm a"
            var time:String = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(todaysDate)
            println("The time is \(time)")
            let id = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("id") as! String!
            println(id)
            let postString = "adminId=\(id)&date=\(date)&time=\(time)&site1=\(siteDescriptions[0])&site2=\(siteDescriptions[1])&site3=\(siteDescriptions[2])&site4=\(siteDescriptions[3])&site5=\(siteDescriptions[4])&site6=\(siteDescriptions[5])&site7=\(siteDescriptions[6])&site8=\(siteDescriptions[7])&site9=\(siteDescriptions[8])&site10=\(siteDescriptions[9])&site11=\(siteDescriptions[10])&site12=\(siteDescriptions[11])&site13=\(siteDescriptions[12])&site14=\(siteDescriptions[13])&site15=\(siteDescriptions[14])&site16=\(siteDescriptions[15])&site17=\(siteDescriptions[16])&site18=\(siteDescriptions[17])&site19=\(siteDescriptions[18])&site20=\(siteDescriptions[19])&site21=\(siteDescriptions[20])&site22=\(siteDescriptions[21])&site23=\(siteDescriptions[22])&site24=&site25="
            println("\(postString)")
            request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
                data, response, error in
                dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
                    self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                    UIApplication.sharedApplication().endIgnoringInteractionEvents()
                }

                if error != nil {
                    println("error=\(error)")
                    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Please check your internet connection", preferredStyle: .Alert)
                    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Cancel, handler: nil))
                    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    return
                }

                var err: NSError?
                var json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableContainers, error: &err) as? NSDictionary
                // Did the JSONObjectWithData constructor return an error? If so, log the error to the console
                if(err != nil) {
                    println(err!.localizedDescription)
                    let jsonStr = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                    println("Error could not parse JSON: '\(jsonStr)'")
                    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Something went wrong. Please try again later.", preferredStyle: .Alert)
                    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Cancel, handler: nil))
                    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
                else{
                    if(json!["status"] as! String == "success"){
                        //Message went successfully
                        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Success", message: "Updates sent successfully", preferredStyle: .Alert)
                        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Cancel, handler: {
                            action in
                            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("backToList", sender: self)
                          //  siteDescriptions = ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""]
                          //  self.listTableView.reloadData()
                        }))
                        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

                    }else{
                        var message = json!["message"] as! String!
                        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: message, preferredStyle: .Alert)
                        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Cancel, handler: nil))
                        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }
                }


            }
            task.resume()

    }
```

The last line in the below code snippet is line 109 -

```
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Cancel, handler: {
                                action in
                                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("backToList", sender: self)
                              //  siteDescriptions = ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""]
                              //  self.listTableView.reloadData()
                            }))
                            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Being unable to solve this, I appealed to the apple review team. Soon after, they approved the app and it is now live on the app store.

Hope this helps someone else.